# how to display text in ckeditor status bar?

Tags: ckeditor, statusbar

I just want to know how to display text in the ckeditor status bar.

At the bottom of the ckeditor displays the elements path I just want to display text in that elements path like status bar.

Foe example, when the user finds and replaces a text in the editor, I want to display to the user the number of instances replaced in the text.

Any help is useful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the elementspath plugin:

```
config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
```

Then make a custom plugin by copying `_source/plugins/elementspath` to `plugins/elementspath`.

Then rename the directory to your custom name and change line 33 of the plugin.js file to use the new name (the CkEditor styleguide calls for all lowercase letters for plugin names):

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'newname',
```

Then add the new plugin in your config:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'newname';
```

---

The `editor.on( 'selectionChange', function( ev )` section is where the majority of the work is done to create the content for that line. The main section is this:

```
html.unshift(
  '<a' +
    ' id="', idBase, index, '"' +
    ' href="javascript:void(\'', name, '\')"' +
    ' tabindex="-1"' +
    ' title="', label, '"' +
    ( ( CKEDITOR.env.gecko && CKEDITOR.env.version < 10900 ) ?
    ' onfocus="event.preventBubble();"' : '' ) +
    ' hidefocus="true" ' +
    ' onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(', onKeyDownHandler, ',', index, ', event );"' +
    extra ,
    ' onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction('+ onClickHanlder, ',', index, '); return false;"',
    ' role="button" aria-labelledby="' + idBase + index + '_label">',
      name,
      '<span id="', idBase, index, '_label" class="cke_label">eee' + label + '</span>',
  'rrrr</a>' );
```

You can modify it to display whatever content you like.

You'll need to look through the rest of the code to understand everything that's happening and make any other changes needed for your specific goals.